# generated serviceaccount token is rejected by kube-apiserver

Tags: kubernetes

I have one successfully working cluster, with out any problems, I've tried to make a copy of it. It's working basically, except one issue - token generated by apiserver is not valid with error message:

```
6 handlers.go:37] Unable to authenticate the request due to an error: crypto/rsa: verification error
```

I have api server started up with following parameters:

```
kube-apiserver --address=0.0.0.0    --admission_control=NamespaceLifecycle,NamespaceExists,LimitRanger,SecurityContextDeny,ServiceAccount,ResourceQuota --service-cluster-ip-range=10.116.0.0/23 --client_ca_file=/srv/kubernetes/ca.crt --basic_auth_file=/srv/kubernetes/basic_auth.csv --authorization-mode=AlwaysAllow  --tls_cert_file=/srv/kubernetes/server.cert --tls_private_key_file=/srv/kubernetes/server.key --secure_port=6443 --token_auth_file=/srv/kubernetes/known_tokens.csv  --v=2 --cors_allowed_origins=.* --etcd-config=/etc/kubernetes/etcd.config --allow_privileged=False
```

I think I'm missing something but can't find what exactly, any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

So, apparently it was wrong server.key used by controller manager. 
According to [kubernetes documentation](http://kubernetes.io/v1.0/docs/admin/service-accounts-admin.html) token is generated by controller manager.

While I was doing copy of the all my configuration, I had to change ipaddress and had to change certificate due to this as well. But controller-manager started with "old" certificate and after the change created wrong keys because server.key.

Comment: The linked URL no longer works. Is this the correct update: https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/service-accounts-admin/ ?

Answer (score 0):

You can see this below flag for api server, it works for me. Check this.

```
--insecure-bind-address=${OS_PRIVATE_IPV4} 
--bind-address=${OS_PRIVATE_IPV4} 
--tls-cert-file=/srv/kubernetes/server.cert 
--tls-private-key-file=/srv/kubernetes/server.key 
--client-ca-file=/srv/kubernetes/ca.crt 
--admission_control=NamespaceLifecycle,NamespaceExists,LimitRanger,SecurityContextDeny,ResourceQuota 
--token-auth-file=/srv/kubernetes/known_tokens.csv 
--basic-auth-file=/srv/kubernetes/basic_auth.csv 
--etcd_servers=http://${OS_PRIVATE_IPV4}:4001 
--service-cluster-ip-range=10.10.0.0/16 
--logtostderr=true 
--v=5
```

Comment: *Which* flag of the seven zillions are you referring to?